# Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException textAlarmPrompt

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I've got this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.thewayto.doland.Acttimer.onCreate(Acttimer.java:52)
```

This is the code, the error is in the third line:

```
       textAlarmPrompt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.alarmprompt);

    buttonstartSetDialog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startSetDialog);
    buttonstartSetDialog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textAlarmPrompt.setText("");
            openTimePickerDialog(false);

        }});

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`buttonstartSetDialog` is probably `null` on that line. Make sure there is a view in your layout with the proper ID, otherwise Android won't find it and `findViewById` returns `null`.

Also see: [What is a Null Pointer Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/218510/1207921)